# What is the history of the use of the word daughter for a decay product in nuclear physics?

Tags: physics, terminology, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

I was browsing the book *Isotopes: Principles and Applications* by Faure and Mensing and I would like to know what is the history of the use of the word daughter for a decay product. It seems to me that the book gives no explanation about the terminology so I think it is a well established convention for a long time.

A quick search gives me this Historical perspective:

> A radionuclide generator is a concept defined as an effective
> radiochemical separation of decaying parent and daughter radionuclides
> such that the daughter is obtained in a pure radionuclidic and
> radiochemical form. Radionuclide generators were historically called
> ‘cows’ since the daughter radioactivity was ‘milked’ (i.e. removed)
> from its precursor and the parent then generated a fresh supply of the
> daughter.<sup>1</sup>

but even if I understand the cow and milk metaphor I do not understand the use of the word daughter, contrasted for example with the word son; moreover, I do not get the asymmetry between daughter, which has a specific gender, and parent, which it seems to me gender neutral.

I know that maybe this question is more suitable for https://english.stackexchange.com/ but I am interested in the context of physics: maybe someone received an explanation about the terminology during a formal nuclear physics university lesson.

In my bookshelf, an Italian author<sup>2</sup> uses the word *discendente* (descendant) that I would consider almost gender neutral; another Italian author<sup>3</sup>, translating from the English, uses the word *figlio* (son).

---

<sup>1</sup>Radionuclide Generators. In : *Handbook of Nuclear Chemistry*. Boston, MA : Springer US, 2004. p. 1379–1415. ISBN 978-0-387-30682-7. Available from: https://doi.org/10.1007/0-387-30682-X_32

<sup>2</sup>Paolo Chiorboli, *Fondamenti di Chimica*, UTET, Torino, 1975 (II edizione, 1980).

<sup>3</sup>Cornelis Klein, Anthony R. Philpotts
*Mineralogia e petrografia*
Prima edizione italiana condotta sulla seconda edizione inglese
A cura di Giorgio Gasparotto, Roberto Braga. Zanichelli, Bologna, 2018.

Comment: Probably this concept was in German before English.  So: what word was used there?

Comment: The *Oxford English Dictionary* has its first example of this usage in English dated 1915.

Comment: Just a thought: around 1915, the decay chains of uranium and thorium were explored (by Rutherford and Soddy). As a decay chain contains different element names, someone might have thought it resembled a _female_ ancestral line in genealogy.

Comment: G. v. Hevesy and F. Paneth, "Lehrbuch der Radioaktivität." Leipzig: J. A. Barth 1923, p. 74 (my emphasis): "Ein Radioelement befindet sich mit seinem Zerfallprodukt im radioaktiven Gleichgewicht, wenn in der Zeiteinheit ebenso viele Atome der **Tochtersubstanz** zerfallen, wie entstehen"

Comment: A German [source](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Verhandlungen_der_Gesellschaft_Deutscher/5Fk3AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) from 1910 speaks of "mother substances" and "daughter substances" and that there is a "genetic connection" between radioactive elements: "Da die radioaktiven Elemente gruppenweise in einem genetischen Zusammenhang stehen, derart, daß jedes einzelne Radioelement die Tochtersubstanz eines anderen und selbst wieder die Muttersubstanz eines dritten Radioelementes ..." Unfortunately I can't tease out the name of the actual paper from Google Books.

Comment: It's a report of a talk at a meeting.  "7 . Herr E . EBLER - Heidelberg : Über die Radioaktivität der Mineralquellen" ,on "pages" 292ff of the Hathi Trust version, https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.$b522144&view=1up&seq=293&q1=Tochtersubstanz

Comment: FWIW, over in animal husbandry,  children are described as "out of " the mother and "by" the father.  Perhaps viewing atoms as "mothers" led to viewing the decay products (often atoms as well) as of the same gender.

Comment: The 1906 German translation of J.J. Thomson's [_Conduction of electricity through gasses_ ](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015067307796&view=1up&seq=354&q1=tochtersubstanz) uses " Mutter- und Tochtersubstanz bekannten Radioaktivitätskonstanten ..."

Comment: @njuffa I do not know German, but in Italian **substanz** in Tochtersubstanz is *sostanza* which has a female gender.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson In German the grammatical gender of substance is also female: *die Substanz*.

Comment: @njuffa If you like to make an answer I will upvote it for sure. Up to now the German Tochtersubstanz is a good explanation to me.

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipedia, a decay product is also referred to as a daughter product, a daughter isotope, radio-daughter or daughter nuclide.

The term possibly arose from cell biology where it is common to call the cells after division daughter cells, possibly because they too can go on to divide. In fact, it is documented that the term fission was borrowed from cell biology:

In 1938, Lise Meitner spent Christmas at the home of her friend Eva von Bahr and whilst there, she received a letter from Otto Hahn describing his chemical proof that some of the products of the bombardment of uranium with neutrons were barium. No previous known method of radioactive decay could account for such a large product and she wrote back to Hahn to say:

> At the moment, the assumption of such a thoroughgoing breakup seems very difficult to me, but in nuclear physics we have experienced so many surprises, that one cannot unconditionally say: "it is impossible".

Later, after a walk in the woods with her nephew Otto Frisch, in fact in the midst of one, Meitner & Frisch correctly interpreted Hahn's results as the splitting of the uranium atom. Frisch decided that he needed a name for this new process and spoke to William Arnold, an American biologist and asked him what biologists called the process by which living cells divided into two cells. Arnold informed him that the term was *fission* and Frisch duly used the term in his joint paper with Meitner submitted to *Nature* describing the phenomenon of uranium fission. As the term fission was new, he used it in quotes. However, it was the first and last time that the term fission was used in quotes as the term was quickly assimilated into the vocabulary of nuclear physics.